# Data drop duplicates data complex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

```
import pandas as pd

search = pd.DataFrame({
  "Code": ["BB", "BB", "CC", "CC", "CC", "DD", "DD"],
  "N1": [22, 20, 33, 30, 31, 44, 40]
})

confirmed = pd.DataFrame({'N2': [30, 40, 50]})
```

Hi dear, I have a question while learning Python/pandas for data analysis. I have two dataframes above, I wish to search the data value in the comfirmed df, and if the value matches/appears in the first df (search), then we keep that value and its corresponding "Code" and delete the other same Code value. For example, 30 in the "confirmed" df, and it also appears in the "search" dataframe, so we keep value 30 and its code "CC", meanwhile we delete the other "CC"s and values (33, 31). Same for the others.

In the end, the "search" dataframe should look like this:

```
  Code  N1
0   BB  22
1   BB  20
2   CC  30
3   DD  40
```

It is quite complex question for me as a Python data rookie, so if anyone has any ideas, please help. Great thanks.

Comment: Why is row `BB. 22` not removed?

Comment: Hi Erfan, thanks for contacting, because I want to search values in the "comfirmed" df first, and if there are no any values that match the values in the "Search" df, we won't delete it. But, if there is any value in "comfirmed" df that appears in the first df (search), then we keep that value and its corresponding "Code" and delete the other same Code values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with `transform` after `isin` check

```
s=search.N1.isin(confirmed.N2)
m=(~s).groupby(search['Code']).transform('all') | s
out=search[m]
out
  Code  N1
0   BB  22
1   BB  20
3   CC  30
6   DD  40
```

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S thank you so much for your answer! that perfectly solve my question. But I am a rookie for python data analysis, your codes are a bit complex for me to understand. Is that possible you explain a little bit or any links related your reference? Really appreciate it.

Comment: @XaviorL first we check which value in df2, then we groupby , if all of the value in the group, we keep it , if not we only pick the value in df2 .

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S, thank you for the explanation. I will keep learning until I can fully understand them. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Yorben_s' answer, but with `np.where` as well:

```
df = search.copy()
df['flag'] = np.where((df['N1'].isin(comfirmed['N2'])), 1, 0)
df['flag'] = np.where((df.groupby('Code')['flag'].transform(sum) == 0), 1, df['flag'])
df = df.loc[df['flag'] == 1].drop('flag', axis=1)
df
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting as answer but Yorben_s is probably a bit more pythonic.

Comment: hi @David Erickson, thanks a lot, your answer is great as well.